# How do you create a Monitor Client using a specific api-version?

Tags: azure-sdk-python

I am trying to call a specific version of the ARM API:
`2017-03-01-preview`

In a normal REST API call, you would be able to specify `api-version=2017-03-01-preview`, however I see no similar option using the Azure Python SDK.

Specifically trying to create a new Monitor Client against this API version.
http://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_azure-monitor.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I will answer to your specific question about Monitor. This is considered to be advanced, and we can't provide guarantee that the deserialisation will work. `raw=True` should be used to get the JSON and do not try deserialisation (`raw=True` is not available for list operations). The API Version is an attribute at the operation group level:

```
client = MonitorClient(**parameters)
# 2015-05-05 for instance (fake value, I don't know monitor Api Version history)
client.metric_definitions.api_version = "2015-05-05"
```

If you really need to call an older Api version with a 100% guarantee that the call will work, you can use the `azure-mgmt-resource` package and generic call:

```
    get_result = self.resource_client.resources.get(
        resource_group_name=group_name,
        resource_provider_namespace="Microsoft.Compute",
        parent_resource_path="",
        resource_type="availabilitySets",
        resource_name=resource_name,
        api_version="2015-05-01-preview",
    )
```

Note that we are adding the multi-api version support to package currently. This is already supported in `azure-mgmt-(compute/resource/storage/network/containerregistry)`

These packages have a `api_version` parameter, which means that you receive the correct class based on this `api_version`.

(I own the SDK at MS)

Edit: improve text with raw=True

Comment: I haven't tested the second option yet, but I wanted to update you that the first option did not seem to work. I set the api_version to `2017-03-01-preview` and looked for the property I need, and did not see it. The results looked the same as before, so I did a sanity check, and updated the api_version to garbage data `1-1-1`. I still got the same results back, which implies to me that this property does not actually affect the call being made.

Comment: When I say "we can't provide guarantee that the class we are building will match what an older API version will return", this means that we are using the same model and then expected set of attributes. New attributes cannot be there, since we don't know how to parse them. I should have mentionned you can use "raw=True" to get the original JSON and get your new attribute. Note that I insist the `api_version` attribute is working as expected: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-monitor/azure/monitor/operations/metric_definitions_operations.py